# Как изменить размер картинки в Button?

Tags: android, button

У меня есть `Button` внутри которой справа находится картинка `(drawableEnd="@drawable/support")`, но она отображается слишком маленькой. Какие атрибуты использовать в `xml-файле`, чтобы задать размер картинки внутри `Button`?

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/support"
        android:text="@string/support"/>
```

Comment: паддинг уберите

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот такая кнопка в рабочем приложении, изображение на кнопке располагается так, как нужно, на всю ширину и длину. Может, Вам подойдет такое решение:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/someBtnId"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:padding="0px"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_cauldron_gray"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Программно:

```
Button myBtn = findViewById(R.id.my_btn);

Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_action_name);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0,
        drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*3,
        drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*3);

ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, 0, 0);
btn.setCompoundDrawables(sd.getDrawable(), null, null, null);
```

Размер указываете в:

```
drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*3,
drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*3);
```